Despite Vritrasura, are other dragons mentioned in the scriptures?
I know that Vritrasura is mentioned as dragon in Vedas, from this question. However, i also wanted to know about is any other mentions of dragons in any scripture.
So my question is, despite Vritrasura, are other dragons mentioned in any of scriptures? If yes, pls answer to this question.

I recently added a link about this at my question. You can see that.
